# Convergence of an increasing + bounded function in L^1 implies convergence in probability and vice versa

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

I've encountered this problem which I am a little baffled by, was wondering if anyone could help shed some light on it:

Suppose we have $f:[0,\infty) \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ a bounded and increasing function s.t. $f(z)>0$ for $z>0$, and $f(z)\downarrow 0$ as $z \downarrow 0$.

How can it be proven that $Z_n \rightarrow 0$ in probability iff $\mathbb{E}[f(|Z_n|)] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$?

I get that we can use Chebyshev's inequality to show that $\mathbb{E}[f(|Z_n|)] \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(f(|Z_n|)>\epsilon)\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ for $n\rightarrow \infty$, but am not sure of how to go from there to proving that $\mathbb{P}(|Z_n|>\epsilon)\epsilon \rightarrow 0 $ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ holds...

Appreciate any insight! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If $Z_n$ does not converge to $0$ in probability then there is $\varepsilon > 0$ and a subsequence $Z_{n_k}$ such that $$\mathbb{P}(|Z_{n_k}| \leq \varepsilon) \geq \varepsilon$$ for every $k$.

Since $f$ is non-negative and increasing, one can conclude for an arbitrary $k$ that
$$\mathbb{E}[f(|Z_{n_k}|)] \geq \mathbb{E}[f(\varepsilon) 1_{\{|Z_{n_k}| > \varepsilon\}}] \geq f(\varepsilon) (1-\varepsilon) > 0$$
but the left hand side goes to $0$ so this is a contradiction.

Conversely, suppose that $Z_n \to 0$ in probability. Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $f$ goes to $0$ at $0$, we can find a $\delta > 0$ such that $0<x \leq \delta$ implies $f(x) < \frac{\varepsilon}{2}$. Then by the convergence in probability, there is an $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $\mathbb{P}(|Z_n| > \delta) \leq \varepsilon\cdot [2 \sup_{x \in [0,\infty)} f(x)]^{-1}$.

We can then write for $n \geq N$,
$$\mathbb{E}[f(|Z_n|)] = \mathbb{E}[f(|Z_n|) (1_{\{|Z_n| \leq \delta\}} + 1_{\{|Z_n| > \delta\}})] \leq f(\delta) + \sup_{x \in [0,\infty)} f(x) \mathbb{P}(|Z_n| > \delta) \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2} + \frac{\varepsilon}{2} = \varepsilon$$
Therefore $\mathbb{E}[f(|Z_n|)] \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$.